# How to find a bounded sequences with three sub-sequences that converge to three different limits.

Tags: general-topology

The question is about finding a bounded sequence with three sub-sequences that converge to three different limits.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried

Comment: you got 3 answers in less than a minute, is that a record ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build it: $a_{3n}=0$, $a_{3n+1}=1$, $a_{3n+2}=2$, $n=1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: sorry for my being ignorance, what is the formula here?

Comment: No formula needed, just the sequence is well defined as written (the formula is $a_n:= n-3\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$)

Comment: what do you think about cos nπ/2. How can I divide this into three subsequences that converge to three different numbers

Comment: $\cos (n\pi/2)$ is $1$ if $n$ is multiple of $4$, $-1$ if $n$ is even but not multiple of $4$, $0$ if $n$ odd.

Answer (score 2):

It’s late, but I can’t resist:

> Time<sub>1</sub> to<sub>2</sub> go<sub>3</sub> waltz<sub>1</sub>ing<sub>2</sub> and<sub>3</sub> count<sub>1</sub>ing<sub>2</sub> the<sub>3</sub> beats<sub>1</sub> as<sub>2</sub> you<sub>3</sub> try<sub>1</sub> not<sub>2</sub> to<sub>3</sub> step<sub>1</sub> on<sub>2</sub> your<sub>3</sub> poor<sub>1</sub> part<sub>2</sub>ner’s<sub>3</sub> feets<sub>1</sub> ...

Answer (score 0):

try the sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...$ and subsequences $1,1,1,...$, $2,2,2,...$, and $3,3,3,...$

Answer (score 0):

What about $\cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$?

Comment: how are we going to define subsequences here?